# Admin menu items disappearing

Tags: administrator

Weird thing happend to one of my websites:

In admin panel (Joomla! 3.3.1 Stable - default backend template) after I **click an item from the top dropdown menu** (Articles for example) and then click anywhere on screen, **the menu item disappears**.

What happens in the code is that there is dynamically added inline css saying:

```
display: none
```

You can see in this video:
http://screencast.com/t/EmWxcDiCg0x

Can somebody help me? What can be causing that strange behavior?

**EDIT**:

Also, when I hover over the view counters in the "popular articles" section in the dashboard, they disappear on mouse out. Strange vanishings can also be seen in few other places.

I think it may have something to do with bootstrap js, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: No a default Joomla thing, most likely a script from one of your extensions. Or have you maybe been messing around with core JS files?

Comment: I did not install any extension I wouldn't use on my other sites. And I certainly was not snooping around core JS files. I think, but I cannot be sure, that all of this started after installing one of the AkeebaBackup updates. I didn't notice the error for a long time and all backups that I have are corrupted by this.

Comment: What happens if you disable (not uninstall) Akeeba Backup in the Extension Manager?

Comment: Still the same :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've solved my problem, but I still don't know what exactly caused this. Although it doesn't really matter - the important thing is everything works now.

What helped was replacing all the files from **media/jui/js** folder with the files from working Joomla installation. That's all.

One or more of them must have gotten corrupted during installation or update of some extension.